# what function I need to use to save my workbook and convert it to PDF?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I need to Save my spreadsheet and convert it to pdf, then merge it with multiple another Pdf's.... what function or module I can use?

Comment: For exporting worksheet to PDF, see [ExportAsFixedFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat) method.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.